# Dropwizard thread count going 3k making application responses slow

Tags: java, multithreading, dropwizard, newrelic, jedis

Facing issues related to thread after checking thread profiler in New Relic

98% sun.misc.Unsafe.park(boolean, long) :native
    89% java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(java.lang.Object, long) :215
        88% java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(long) :2078
            86% org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit) :392
                 86% org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.idleJobPoll() :563
                    86% org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.access$800(org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool) :48
                        86% org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run() :626
                            86% java.lang.Thread.run() :745

Screenshot also attached.

[image]

The functionality is build using Dropwizard java framework for emmiting messages through websockets using Jedis(https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/Getting-started). Emitting of messages is done asynchronously using runAsync().

Actually we have 2 stacks stack1 and stack2 both have same configurations. Where stack1 is performing very well in serving both web requests as well as this funcitonality at rpm around 20k but stack2 is taking too much time which is dedicately used for serving only this functionality at only 5k rpm. Stack2  thread count spike goes 2000 to 3000 while stack1 not showing such spike at the same time of analysis.

We are using AWS EC2 instances of type m4.large. Please help me if I may be doing something in wrong way.

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball is currently out of order :( Can you please provide isntead some code?